# Are deore 9 speed shifters compatible with Alivio & Altus derailleurs?

Tags: shifter, hybrid-bike

I have a 3x9 hybrid with an Alivo RD and Altus FD. The shifters are Altus. Can I upgrade my shifters to Deore M590 without changing my derailleurs?

I plan on changing my derailleurs in the future but don't want to do it all in one go to spread the cost.

I did look at the 105 flatbar shifters but then I would have to change everything and I don't think there is an upgrade "path" short of buying a new bike

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can take any 7-9 speed Shimano rear derailleur and use it with any Shimano 7-9 rear shifter. And the Deore front shifter will pair fine with the Altus FD.

Answer (score 0):

Not all rear derailleurs designated as just seven speed will handle the inboard movement of a 9-speed with unit. Most of those are the very old units which operate very well but will not reliably swing inward enough.

Comment: Is this a general comment, or does it specifically apply to the Alivo derailleur mentioned in the question?